# How can I output the list of files in a directory in double-quotes?

Tags: windows, cmd

How to enclose each line resulted from command line `dir/b /s /c *.txt` inside quotations

```
dir/b /s /c *.txt
```

The command displays all the txt file available in the directory. I need the path of each file inside double quotes

Comment: Why the `/C` option? That has no effect when you also use `/B`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `for` command, for example, this outputs all the requested files into a file named `x.x`:

```
(for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /s /c *.txt') do @echo "%f") > x.x
```

Note that if you use this in a batch file (ie. not directly from the command prompt), you have to escape the `%` char as `%%`, ie:

```
(for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s /c *.txt') do @echo "%%f") > x.x
```

Also, if you have PowerShell on the computer (server Windows do from version 2k3 or so, I'm not sure; you can install it of course), that's an even more powerful command-line tool - it basically gives you a fully fledged .NET language to do even complex administration tasks. However, I tend to use simple tools for simple tasks, and this is still a simple task :)